# MySQL specific sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following fields: `last_update`, `votes` & `uptime`.

Now, how would you select all tables with `last_update > 0` **first** and then it should select `last_update = 0`. Then sort everything on the amount of `votes` and finally, `uptime`.

`last_update > 0` and `last_update = 0` is really important, because it will put the server on top of the list, or at the bottom.

It should **NOT** sort last_update! Only sort if `last_update > 0` and `last_update = 0`.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY votes DESC, last_update DESC, uptime_pct DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with the [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) `[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position} [ASC | DESC], ...]` it's possibile to have an expression syntax in order by.

So your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY last_update>0 DESC, votes DESC, uptime_pct DESC
```

Comment: Wow. I dint know ORDER BY columnname <operator> value also works. Thanks @chumkiu.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM servers 
WHERE last_update > 0 
ORDER BY last_update DESC, votes DESC, uptime_pct DESC
```

**Update:**

To select rows with `last_update > 0` and `last_update = 0`:

```
SELECT * FROM servers 
ORDER BY last_update DESC, votes DESC, uptime_pct DESC
```

This query:

- Select all rows from `servers`
- Server with recent update will displayed topmost, server with no updates (`last_update = 0`) displayed on bottom.
- If two server have the same `last_update`, the one with highest votes will be displayed first.
- If two server have the same `last_update` and `votes`, the one with highest `uptime_pct` will be displayed first.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is, all last_update > 0 and this list should be sorted on the basis of votes and uptime_pct then you want the list of all rows with last_update = 0.

```
SELECT * FROM servers 
 WHERE last_update > 0 
ORDER BY last_update DESC, 
         votes DESC, 
         uptime_pct DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM servers 
 WHERE last_update = 0 
ORDER BY votes DESC, 
         uptime_pct DESC
```